# Save document to specific collection. Error if collection doesn't exist

Tags: mongoose

I have created a `schema` in `mongoose`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
});

const Question = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;
```

I understand that if I create an instance of `Question` and call `save`, `mongoose` will save the document in `collection` named `questions`.

```
q = Question({
        description: "some description",
        hints: ["hint1", "hint2"],
        topic: 'area'
      });
      await q.save()
```

I don't want that. I want that `q` is saved in a collection based on the `topic` (eg. `area` in the example above). If `area` doesn't exist then `save` should fail. Is that possible?